# Wait for result of click event to finish loading before calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to execute a function that is triggered by a user clicking on a link on my website. However, the data required to execute that function is not available until the next page (i.e. the page the link goes to) has been fully loaded. I know there are lots of articles out there relating to $(document).ready and window.onload but that seems to wait for the page that the link is on, rather than wait for the next page to be loaded. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).on("click", "#SidebarLink", function () {
     // track the user click event 
     getData();        
});

function getData() { 
     // takes information using Jquery from the loaded page 
}
```

I have tried including a document ready function inside both of these but it hasn't worked, and I am stuck on where to go next. Is anyone able to please point me in the right direction of how I wait for the next page that the link goes to to be loaded before executing the "getData" function? I need it to be triggered by the click of the link, as this is what I am tracking for user analytics.

Comment: If the user is changing pages, the script being referenced is no longer being processed. Execute whatever function you are trying to do in a document.ready function in a script tag on the target page.

Comment: @Laif so is there no way of waiting to execute the function after the click event on the first page until the second page has loaded?

Comment: when you leave the page, the script you were processing isn't there anymore. It was called on the previous page and not the current one. It doesn't persist on the browser. Consider either calling the function in the new page or using something asynchronous like PHP